# Show Cluster Bounds always

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I'm looking for a way to make the Bounds of a clusters permanently visible, not only on mouseover. So far I didn't find a solution. I'm using the markercluster plugin for leaflet. I have to insert Datapoints with an Information about the local Bandwidth. I want those to get clustered and then the Area to get outlined by a specific colour. Thanks for your support guys :-)

Greetings 
Matthes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution:

I add the Coverage as a Polygone with the getConvexHull Function. These Polygones I add into a layergroup. This Layergroup ist then allways applied to the map, when an animnation ist done. Before the loop generates the ConvexHull of each cluster, all Layers of the Layergroup get deleted, so there are no bound rendered on the map.

This is the Code `[https://jsfiddle.net/mad__97/3v7hd2vx/211/][1]`

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO!

You should simply use the private method [`_showCoverage()`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/blob/master/src/MarkerClusterGroup.js#L862-L874) of Leaflet.markercluster plugin, and provide it with an object with at least `layer` member being the cluster object which you want to show coverage of.

```js
mcg._showCoverage({ layer: cluster }); // cluster is NOT your cluster group!
```

But you need to be outside of your cluster group animation, and the cluster must have more than 2 children.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/208/

Comment: Thank you. BUt in this case you can only see the Coverage of one cluster. I want to see the Coverage of all clusters, wich are displayed. I think the Problem is, that the function _showCoverage deletes all other Coverages wich were generated before, so at the time always just one is shown. 

I'll try to find a workaround. Whatever if you know how to do this I would appreciate some more help.